# geth console - web3.isConnected function and not a function?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, console

I am trying to find out if my node is connected. So I attach geth via `geth attach` in another terminal. But if I run `web3.isConnected` it returns
`function()`. But when I run it as a function `web3.isConnected()` I get an error `'isConnected' is not a function`.

That's pretty weird behavior.

Comment: By the time I worked with it, isConnected was there but not working at all. Not sure they have fixed it yet. Maybe check the goethereum path notes.